# Simple mean model for time series prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have some historical dataset where I have the measure of a concentrate at different times of the day and I just want to create a simple model to predict the measure in the future.

So, the measurements are done at 15 minutes interval and my dataset looks as follows:

```
timestamp,concentrate
2019-08-01 00:00:00,872.0
2019-08-01 00:15:00,668.0
2019-08-01 00:30:00,604.0
2019-08-01 00:45:00,788.0
2019-08-01 01:00:00,608.0
2019-08-01 01:15:00,692.0
2019-08-01 01:30:00,716.0
2019-08-01 01:45:00,692.0
2019-08-01 02:00:00,672.0
2019-08-01 02:15:00,636.0
2019-08-01 02:30:00,596.0
2019-08-01 02:45:00,748.0
2019-08-01 03:00:00,424.0
2019-08-01 03:15:00,596.0
2019-08-01 03:30:00,936.0
2019-08-01 03:45:00,976.0
2019-08-01 04:00:00,912.0
2019-08-01 04:15:00,1100.0
2019-08-01 04:30:00,1312.0
2019-08-01 04:45:00,1904.0
2019-08-01 05:00:00,2232.0
2019-08-01 05:15:00,3104.0
2019-08-01 05:30:00,4100.0
2019-08-01 05:45:00,4836.0
2019-08-01 06:00:00,4476.0
2019-08-01 06:15:00,4032.0
2019-08-01 06:30:00,1744.0
2019-08-01 06:45:00,2416.0
2019-08-01 07:00:00,2396.0
2019-08-01 07:15:00,1400.0
2019-08-01 07:30:00,5336.0
2019-08-01 07:45:00,4872.0
2019-08-01 08:00:00,5820.0
2019-08-01 08:15:00,5376.0
2019-08-01 08:30:00,5528.0
2019-08-01 08:45:00,5344.0
2019-08-01 09:00:00,5356.0
2019-08-01 09:15:00,5036.0
2019-08-01 09:30:00,5116.0
....
```

So one thing I am doing is calculating the mean and variance at the different times of the day using this historical data and want to use this to do the forecast. I guess this assumes IID but let us not worry about that for the moment.

My question is using this sort of model does one usually output the mean value as the prediction or should I sample from the distribution with this calculated mean and variance and output the sampled value as a prediction?

Comment: Sampling will give you a random result. Good, if you want to do Monte Carlo on a large sample of possible predictions. If there is going to be only one prediction, there is no reason to add randomness to that.

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard!